# C# Script LDAP not returning All Groups

Tags: c#, ssis, ldap

Having a bit of problem with some C# LDAP Queries. The immediately most concerting one is that I appear to be missing approximately 1/3rd of the expected data set.

Have two screen shots attached of the result set.

[image: SSIS Results Count for C# Script]

[image: Powershell Get-AdGroup -Filter * Result Count]

In regards to the C# Filter

I am generating the filter here

```
  public string GenerateFilter()
    {
        var LastRunDateTime = Variables.LastRunDateTime;
        var filter = "(ObjectClass=group)";

        /*
        string filter = string.Format(
             "(&(ObjectClass=group)(whenChanged>={0:yyyyMMddHHmmss.0Z}))",//This is the DateTime format it takes.
             LastRunDateTime.AddHours(-11) // Always use UTC to make life easy. Otherwise you need to change the above time formatting.
       );                    */
        return filter;
    }
```

*I have commented out the initial code which is returning the same count for the first run*

In Regards to the work horse part of the code I can't see any reason why it isn't returning all the values.

I have been checking out the missing values (managed to track them down with a bit of logic) and there is literally no configuration difference between them.

```
    public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
        /*
          Add rows by calling the AddRow method on the member variable named "<Output Name>Buffer".
          For example, call MyOutputBuffer.AddRow() if your output was named "MyOutput".
        */
        DataTable workTable = new DataTable("Ad_Users");
        DataColumn workColumn = workTable.Columns.Add("SID", typeof(string));
        workTable.Columns.Add("ObjectCategory", typeof(string));
        workTable.Columns.Add("ObjectGUID", typeof(string));
        workTable.Columns.Add("CanonicalName", typeof(string));
        workTable.Columns.Add("SAMAccount", typeof(string));
        workTable.Columns.Add("distinguishedName", typeof(string));
        workTable.Columns.Add("DisplayName", typeof(string));
        workTable.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
        workTable.Columns.Add("WhenCreated", typeof(DateTime));
        workTable.Columns.Add("WhenChanged", typeof(DateTime));
        // workTable.Columns.Add("MemberOf", typeof(string));

        var domainController = "[REDACTED]";
        using (var domain = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domainController))
        {
            using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(domain, GenerateFilter()))
            {
                searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("ObjectSID");
                searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("ObjectCategory");
                searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("ObjectGuid");
                searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("CN");
                searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("SAMAccountName");
                searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("DisplayName");
                searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
                searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Description");
                searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("WhenCreated");
                searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("WhenChanged");
                //  searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("MemberOf");

                foreach (SearchResult result in searcher.FindAll())
                {
                    var de = result.GetDirectoryEntry();

                    var sidInBytes = (byte[])de.Properties["ObjectSID"].Value;
                    var GUID = (byte[])de.Properties["ObjectGuid"].Value;
                    Guid guid = new Guid(GUID);

                    //INSERT VALUES INTO DATATABLE
                    DataRow workRow = workTable.NewRow();
                    workRow["SID"] = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(sidInBytes, 0);
                    workRow["ObjectCategory"] = de.Properties["ObjectCategory"].Value;
                    workRow["ObjectGUID"] = guid;
                    workRow["CanonicalName"] = de.Properties["CN"].Value;
                    workRow["SAMAccount"] = de.Properties["SAMAccountName"].Value;
                    workRow["DisplayName"] = de.Properties["DisplayName"].Value;
                    workRow["distinguishedName"] = de.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value;
                    workRow["Description"] = de.Properties["Description"].Value;
                    workRow["WhenCreated"] = Convert.ToDateTime(de.Properties["WhenCreated"].Value);
                    workRow["WhenChanged"] = Convert.ToDateTime(de.Properties["WhenChanged"].Value);

                    Output0Buffer.AddRow();
                    Output0Buffer.ObjectSID = workRow["SID"].ToString();
                    Output0Buffer.ObjectCategory = workRow["ObjectCategory"].ToString();
                    Output0Buffer.ObjectGUID = workRow["ObjectGUID"].ToString();
                    Output0Buffer.CanonicalName = workRow["CanonicalName"].ToString();
                    Output0Buffer.SamAccountName = workRow["SAMAccount"].ToString();
                    Output0Buffer.DisplayName = workRow["DisplayName"].ToString();
                    Output0Buffer.DistinguishedName = workRow["distinguishedName"].ToString();
                    Output0Buffer.Description = workRow["Description"].ToString();
                    Output0Buffer.WhenCreated = Convert.ToDateTime(workRow["WhenCreated"]);
                    Output0Buffer.WhenChanged = Convert.ToDateTime(workRow["WhenChanged"]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone would be able to assist it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get comparable results you should use

```
Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(objectClass=group)"
```